# Markdown syntax differences to start a mermaid block

Tags: azure-devops, markdown, mermaid

It seems to me that git and off-line markdown editors support a quote-syntax to mark a Mermaid block.

```` ``` markdown
<my diagram>
``` ````

It appears that Azure devops went their own way and mark the block with a colon syntax.

`::: markdown
<my diagram>
:::`

The different tools do not seem to support each other's variants; so I have to choose and always edit diagrams either in azure or an offline tool - I cannot mix them. My question is if someone can suggest a way to maybe allow both online and offline editing? It seems rather cumbersome to write a parser that reads my off-line edits and change them to colons before committing offline changes to the server, but that is about the only solution I can think of. Are there easier ways to deal with this?